# Vector of vector pointer memory allocation

Tags: c++

First I want to say that, I have a vector which has thousand of vectors inside. Each of these inside vectors has thousand of numbers inside. I want to keep memory management safe and memory usage at minimum as much as possible.

I want to ask that if I have a code similiar to below

```
    int size = 10;
vector<vector<double>>* something = new vector<vector<double>>(size);

vector<double>* insideOfSomething;
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    insideOfSomething = &(something->at(i));
    //...
    //do something with insideOfSomething 
    //...
}
```

I know that 'something' will be created in heap. What I don't understand is where the vectors are placed, 'insideOfSomething' points? If they are created in stack, then this means that I have a vector pointer, which points a vector in heap, that has vectors inside which are created in stack? (I'm very confused right now.)

If I have a code similiar to the one below;

```
    vector<vector<double>*>* something = new vector<vector<double>*>(size);
vector<double>* insideOfSomething;
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    something->at(i) = new vector<double>();
    insideOfSomething = something->at(i);
    //...
    //do something with inside insideOfSomething 
    //...
}
```

right know all of my vectors are stored in heap, right?

Which one is more usefull according to the memory management?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take a random, simplistic implementation of vector, as I think this will help you.

```
template <class T, class Alloc>
class vector
{
private:
    T* buffer;
    std::size_t vector_size;
    std::size_t vector_capacity
    Alloc alloc;

public:
    ...
};
```

In this case, if we write:

```
vector<int> v;
v.push_back(123);
```

... the pointer, `buffer`, the integrals: `vector_size` and `vector_capacity`, and the allocator object, `alloc`, will all be created on the stack (along with allocating any additional memory necessary for structure padding and alignment).

However, vector itself will allocate memory on the heap to which this `buffer` pointer will store its base address. That will always be on the heap and will contain the actual contents of the vector as we think of them.

This is still more efficient than this:

```
vector<int>* v = new vector<int>;
v->push_back(123);
...
delete v;
```

... as this would involve a heap allocation/deallocation for the vector itself (including its data members) in addition to the memory vector itself allocates for its internal contents (the buffer). It also introduces an additional level of indirection.

Now if we have a vector of `Somethings` (vector of vector or anything else):

```
vector<Something> v;
```

Those `Something` instances are always going to be allocated within a contiguous heap buffer since they would reside in the dynamically allocated memory blocks that vector creates and destroys internally.

Answer (score 7):

You should avoid allocating vectors on the heap and just declare them on the stack since the vector will manage its objects on the heap for you. Anywhere you want to avoid creating a copy you can just use a reference or `const` reference (which ever is necessary).

```
vector<vector<double> > something(size);

for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    vector<double> &insideOfSomething = something.at(i);

    //use insideOfSomething
}
```

Comment: An interesting [related read about copy elision](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/).

Comment: copy elision doesn't seem relevant here, as tehre's no copies in this sample

Answer (score 3):

In vector<> all data stored in heap
And i think you should simply use

```
vector< vector<double> > something;
```

Comment: The actual aggregate contents of the vector, yes. But the vector object generally contains some additional pointers or integrals and those, along with the vector object itself, can exist on the stack as your code points out.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to keep memory management safe and memory usage at minimum as much as possible.

Then

```
vector<vector<double>>* something = new vector<vector<double>>(size);
```

is already not good. As said in the other answers, `vector` already has its data on the heap, no need to mess around with `new` to achieve this. In fact, the objects' location is like

```
       S t a c k                              H e a p

                                        (vector<double>) sthng[0]
(vector<vector<double>>) sthng          (vector<double>) sthng[1]
                                                ...
                                             - - - - - -
                                         (double) sthng[0][0]
                                         (double) sthng[0][1]
                                                ...
                                             - - - - - -
                                         (double) sthng[1][0]
                                         (double) sthng[1][1]
                                                ...
```

(of course, there is no particular ordering of the blocks on the heap)

Answer (score 0):

Joe and hired777's answers explain that a vector will be allocated on the heap no matter what. I'll try to give some insight on the reason for this.

A vector is a resizeable container. Generally it doubles in size when it reaches capacity which means it needs to be able to allocate more memory than it had already allocated. Hence even when you declare vector inside a function and hence on the stack, internally it's holding a pointer to it's data on the heap and on going out of the function's scope, it's destructor will delete this data from the heap.